# RecursiveDirectoryIterator Error on phpunit with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpunit

I'm trying to do unit test of wordpress plugin by phpunit(ver 4.2.6).
But when I run phpunit command, this error occurs:

> 1) SampleTest::testSample
>   UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/tmp/wordpress/wp-content/uploads): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
>
> /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/testcase.php:407
>
> /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/testcase.php:425
>
> /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/testcase.php:26
>
> FAILURES!
>   Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

SampleTest file is just like this.

```
class SampleTest extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    function testSample() {
        $this->assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Have anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I manually created the uploads directory and then the tests ran successfully.

`mkdir /tmp/wordpress/wp-content/uploads`

Seems like the "uploads" folder was just missing.